# re-use browser tab asp.net project F5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-chrome, browser

Every time I make a change to my web api project and hit F5 in Vs 2013 , it opens up a new tab in chrome (or any browser). Is there a way I can configure chrome or vs 2013 so new tabs are not opened and the existing tab is just refreshed when i F5 in vs ? Thanks

Comment: I know you can make it so it doesn't start a new tab but instead allows you to manually F5 in chrome, would that be enough? I'm not sure of a way to auto refresh the current tab though (not sure it's possible).

Comment: As long as IIS Express is running your site would be hosted , you don't require to press F5(debugging mode) for your changes to refresh , just build and press Ctrl + F5 (force to reload cached) on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. I found a setting under vs 2013->project properties->web (below build) that says Dont open page. Wait for request from external app. Then I put a 2 sec meta refresh on my web api test page.